# Python typing: Use a class variable's value as return type of a (mixin) method

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

### Summary

How can I use a class variable's value (which is a class object) as the return type of a (mixin) method with Python typing / mypy?

Here is a minimal example, below you'll find the real, more complicated use case:

```py
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')


class Base(Generic[T]):
    return_type: Type[T]
    value: T  # This attribute is only needed for this minimal example


class Mixin:
    def get(self: Base[T]) -> T:  # mypy: The erased type of self "Base" is not a supertype of its class "Mixin"
        return self.return_type(self.value)  # mypy: Too many arguments for "object"


class Concrete(Mixin, Base[int]):
    return_type = int

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 3


c = Concrete()
x: str = c.get()  # mypy: expected incompatible types (str vs int) error :)
```

I can get rid of the second error when set `Base` as super class of `Mixin`, but that is not really what I want.  I have now idea though, how I can properly define the `return_type: Type[T]`.

I've read the python typing docs as well as the mypy docs, but found nothing.  A web search also didn't yield useful results.

### What I really want to do

I am currently writing a REST client with an architecture similar to [python-gitlab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab):

- The users uses an `ApiClient` class that knows the API URL and does all HTTP requests.
- The API's endpoints are represented by REST manager classes that are attributes of the `ApiClient`.  Depending on the endpoint's functionality, a REST manager can list the endpoint's objects, get a single object, or create, update and delete an object.
- The RestManager returns and receives "dumb" data classes (e.g., [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) or [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) models)
- Concrete REST managers subclass a `RestManager` base class and various mixins for HTTP operations, e.g., a `GetMixin` for getting a single object by ID.
- A concrete REST manager has a class variable that holds the class of the objects that it is going to return.
- In the mixin classes, I want to express "this methods returns an instance of the object class, that the sub-classing restmanager defined as a class variable".

Example usage:

```py
client = ApiClient('https://example.com/myapi/v1')
item = client.items.get(42)
assert isinstance(item, Item)
```

Implementation:

```py
from typing import ClassVar, Type, TypeVar


T = TypeVar(T)


class Item:
    """Data class that represents objects of the "items" endpoint"""
    pass


class ApiClient:
    """Main object that the user works with."""
    def __init__(self, url: str):
        self.url = url
        # There is one manager instance for each endpoint of the API
        self.items = ItemManager(self) 
        # self.cats = CatManager(self)

    def http_get(self, path: str) -> 'Response':
        ...  # Request the proper url and return a response object


class RestManager:
    """Base class for REST managers."""
    _path: ClassVar[str]
    _obj_cls: ClassVar[Type[T]]  # Concrete subclasses set this with an object class, e.g., "Item"

    def __init__(self, client: ApiClient):
        self.client = client

    @property
    def path(self) -> str:
        return self._path


class GetMixin:
    """Mixin for getting a single object by ID"""
    def get(self: RestManager, id: int) -> T:  # Return type is the value the subclass' "_obj_cls" attribute
        response = self.client.http_get(f'{self.path}/{id}')
        return self._obj_cls(**response.json())


class ItemsManager(GetMixin, RestManager):
    """Concrete manager for "Item" objects."""
    _path = '/items'
    _obj_cls = Item  # This is the return type of ItemsManager.get()


client = ApiClient()
item = client.items.get(42)
assert isinstance(item, Item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works.  It is not optimal, because the Mixin classes need to inherit from `RestManager`.  But mypy can successfully deduce the expected return type.

The code requires Pyhton 3.10.  With 3.11, you can import `assert_type` directly from `typing`.  With older versions, you need to use `typing.Type[T]` instead of `type[t]`.

```py
from typing import ClassVar, Generic, TypeVar

from typing_extensions import assert_type


T = TypeVar("T")


class Item:
    """Data class that represents objects of the "items" endpoint"""


class ApiClient:
    """Main object that the user works with."""

    def __init__(self, url: str):
        self.url = url
        # There is one manager instance for each endpoint of the API
        self.items = ItemsManager(self)
        # self.cats = CatManager(self)

    def http_get(self, path: str) -> "Response":
        ...  # Request the proper url and return a response object


class RestManager(Generic[T]):
    """Base class for REST managers."""

    _path: ClassVar[str]
    _obj_cls: type[T]

    def __init__(self, client: ApiClient):
        self.client = client

    @property
    def path(self) -> str:
        return self._path


class GetMixin(RestManager, Generic[T]):
    """Mixin for getting a single object by ID"""

    def get(self, iid: int) -> T:
        response = self.client.http_get(f"{self.path}/{iid}")
        return self._obj_cls(**response.json())


class ItemsManager(GetMixin[Item], RestManager[Item]):
    """Concrete manager for "Item" objects."""

    _path = "/items"
    _obj_cls = Item


def main() -> None:
    client = ApiClient("api")
    item = client.items.get(42)
    assert_type(item, Item)
    assert isinstance(item, Item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** I haven't read your real-world use case carefully so I could be wrong. The following analysis is based on your simplified example.

I don't think this is supported by `mypy`. Currently `mypy` assumes (and rightfully so) that the type of `self` in a method is a subtype of the class.

However, for your mixin to work, there must be a restriction on the kind of classes that it can be mixed with. For example, in your simplified example, the class must have `return_type` and `value` attributes. My suggestion is that you can also add those as annotations for yout mixin class, resulting in something like:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')


class Base(Generic[T]):
    return_type: Type[T]
    value: T  # This attribute is only needed for this minimal example


class Mixin(Generic[T]):
    return_type: Type[T]
    value: T

    def get(self) -> T:  # annotation on `self` can be dropped
        return self.return_type(self.value)
```

Note that the final line is still an error in `mypy`, because it cannot prove that the `__init__` method of `self.return_type` takes only one argument. You can fix this with [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#nominal-vs-structural-subtyping) which was introduced in Python 3.7, but it might be a bit of overkill. IMHO, if you have some simple code that you're pretty sure is right, sometimes a little `# type: ignore` is best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. It does not help me though.  I guess the only solutions that currently works quite (not perfectly) well is to let the Mixin inherit from Base. :-/

Comment: Maybe, the correct approach would be to create a `Protocol` as a base for Mixin classes